# Copying userAccount from One AD Domain to another Domain

Tags: 2007, user-accounts, domain

Is it possible to copy userAccount from One AD Domain e.g, DomainA\User to another Domain e.g, DomainB\User in sharepoint 2007? Is it possible with powershell? And is the copy operation will also copy all the permissions/references associated with userAccount?

I need help with sample powershell script or code snippet to understand

Comment: Both domain have the Trust and user from both domain already in sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

This is 2 step exercise and yes you can keep the permissions intact.

1. you have to move/copy all your required users from Domain A to Domain B. [Check this technet for how to move it using powershell.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617248.aspx)
2. Once all user in Domain B, then you have to run the Migrate User stsadm command to update user profile with correct domain. This will preserve all their permissions.

   stsadm -o migrateuser –oldlogin  –newlogin  [-ignoresidhistory]

[Check this if you want bulk migrate user.](http://www.dotnetscraps.com/dotnetscraps/post/Powershell-Tip-5-Migrate-users-from-one-domain-to-another.aspx)
.